# Is this a valid alternative proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Could you please tell me if this proof is valid, and if not how I could improve on it. Its my own proof of something rather simple, in order to practice proofs, however its different that the one given in my lecture notes.

Let a,b ∈ ℤ,

a|b and b|a if and only if b=±a. Or in symbol form (a|b & b|a) ⇔ (b=±a)

Proof:

Firstly, if b=qa and a=rb for some q,r ∈ ℤ

⇒ a=r(qa)=(rq)a

⇒ 1=rq

⇒ r=±1 & q=±1

⇒ b=±a

Secondly, if b=±a,

⇒ a|b as b=±1·a & b|a as a=±1·b

QED.

Comment: This is correct. But your grammar isn't. The word you want in all instances where you've used it is "it's" with an apostrophe, not "its." (Also, pretty much no one says "Firstly" with -ly. Most people just say: first, second, etc. The adverbs have a needlessly pedantic ring to them.)

Comment: Might need to make a case for $a = 0$ when you do a = r(qa) implies 1 = rq.

Comment: Ah, yes, fleabood is right: I overlooked the $a=0$ case.

Comment: It's a simple case.  If $a = 0$ then $b|0$ means $b=r0=0$

Comment: The proof is indeed correct, and although "firstly" might not be common, I disagree with the rather harsh statement that this sounds "pedantic." (If anyone is pedantic here, it is symplectomorphic nitpicking about grammar when the OP is clearly asking about mathematical correctness of his proof, and then lecturing him on the use of "firstly.")

Comment: Otherwise it's just fine.

Comment: @TMM: I wasn't nitpicking. I was offering practical feedback for a student interested in writing better proofs. Plenty of professional mathematicians on MSE correct users' grammar in the comments, including Mariano and Arturo Magidin. A proof is not just a mathematical thing. It is a piece of writing.

Comment: Looking at the proof from my lecture notes, it did include the case where a=0. Thanks for making it obvious to me as to why I need to include it in my proof.

Comment: Whilst it wasn't necessarily the sort of response I was looking for, I still appreciate your feedback symplectomorphic. Proper grammar is important in a proof.

Comment: @sym Sure, but part of it boils down to a matter of taste. Saying that using certain words "is" pedantic means you are saying your opinion is "the truth", while in reality it's nothing more than your opinion. You are not correcting his grammar there, and whether it comes across as pedantic or not depends on the reader. (Using "first(ly)" and "second(ly)" can also be interpreted as the writer just liking to structure his proof with concrete, "numbered" statements.)

Comment: @TMM: show me a piece of published professional mathematical writing with "firstly" and "secondly." and no, there was no pretense to objective universality: I said "pretty much no one," suggesting some people do, and presumably those people don't think it's pedantic. it was obviously opinion, and in line with mainstream opinion if we take publications to indicate the mainstream. moreover "first" and "second" do the work of structuring with "concrete, 'numbered' statements" just fine: the -ly doesn't add anything. that's all I'll say.